# To delete certain folders in an directory

Tags: vbscript

I need to know how to delete certain folders on specific directory using VB script.
This is my folder structure.

```
C:/WL

1.Dev
2.Local
3.Src123
4.Src456
5.Src789
```

I want to delete all the folders except "Dev". could someone help on this.

I used the following Vb code also, but didn't work.

```
Dim wshell
Dim re : Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^src*"
re.IgnoreCase = True

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  With .GetFolder("C:\WL")
    For Each Folder In .SubFolders
      If Folder.Name <> "dev" Then
        wscript.Echo Folder.Name
        'Wscript.Echo "Should delete the folders"

        set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")

        wshShell.Run  "cmd.exe /D C:\ & RMDIR /S /Q &  Folder.Name"

        If re.Test(Folder.Name) Then Call Folder.Delete(True)
    Next
  End With
End With
```

Comment: For one thing the `If Folder.Name <> "dev" Then` is missing a closing `End If`. If that doesn't help you need to explain in more detail how your code "didn't work".

Comment: What do you mean with _but didn't work_? You missed an `End If` btw.

Comment: I think you might revise your regular expression. To match on a string starting with `src` you need a pattern like `^src.*`. To _not_ match on a folder `Dev`, you need a pattern like `^[^(Dev)].*`

Comment: Don't need a shell to delete folders, just `Folder.Delete` will do. Don't need regex for this simple goal.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Correct the `If / End If` structure of your code

2 - The cmd command you are running does not work. It should be something as

```
wshShell.Run "cmd.exe /c rmdir /s /q """ + folder.Path + """"
```

3 - Why the cmd command ?

```
For Each f In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder("c:\WL").SubFolders
    If LCase(f.Name) <> "dev" Then
        f.Delete
    End If
Next
```